# How to use foreign key as primary key in Doctrine2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

This question is about Symfony2/Doctrine2 schema situation. 
Here is my YAML, without namespaces and fields:

```
Region:
    id:
        id: { type: bigint, id: true, generator: { strategy: IDENTITY } }
    fields: ...

Domain:
    id:
        Region: { associationKey: true }
    fields: ...
    oneToOne:
        Region:
            targetEntity: Region
            joinColumn: { name: departure_city_id, referencedColumnName: id }
```

That works fine. But when I add many2many relation entity symfony profiler gives me an error `DomainRegion Cannot map association 'DomainRegion#Domain as identifier, because the target entity 'Domain' also maps an association as identifier.`

Here is many2many entity schema:

```
DomainRegion:
    id:
        Domain: { associationKey: true }
        Region: { associationKey: true }
    fields: ...
    manyToOne:
        Domain:
            targetEntity: Domain
            inversedBy: DomainRegions
            joinColumn: { name: region_id, referencedColumnName: departure_city_id }
        Region:
            targetEntity: Region
            #inversedBy: DomainRegions
            joinColumn: { name: region_child_id, referencedColumnName: id }
```

Note that `doctrine:generate:entities` and `doctrine:schema:update` works fine with that schema. Website also works fine, the only thing that troubles me is Error in symfony profiler.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074863/mapping-fail-the-entity-class-pi-unidadbundle-entity-horasporunidad-mapping Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you 4 reply, but... I've found that question before posting mine and It's not about my case.